# Spring-security: Я соединил java и xml конфигурацию вместе и получил ensure Spring Security & Spring MVC are configured in a shared ApplicationContext

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

> вот мой проект на гитхабе https://github.com/timpson78/eshop/

я сделал java-security config eshop/src/main/java/config/securityconfig.java и затем добавил его в уже работающий xml-config в файл resources/spring/spring-mvc.xml используя эту аннотацию:  , в файле spring-security.xml я написал  context:component-scan base-package="config"  где мой java-config вызывается посредством сканирования дирректории в которой лежит java-конфигурация
и получил исключение:

> Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
>   instantiate [javax.servlet.Filter]: Factory method
>   'springSecurityFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   bean named 'mvcHandlerMappingIntrospector' available: A Bean named
>   mvcHandlerMappingIntrospector of type
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.HandlerMappingIntrospector is
>   required to use MvcRequestMatcher. Please ensure Spring Security &
>   Spring MVC are configured in a shared ApplicationContext.
>
> вот мой web.xml:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        classpath:spring/spring-app.xml
        classpath:spring/spring-db.xml
        classpath:spring/spring-security.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>


<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:spring/spring-mvc.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>

    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<!-- Spring Security -->
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<filter>
    <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>encoding</param-name>
        <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

> Что я делаю не так?

Comment: День добрый, Тимофей. Не нужно дублировать вопросы, лучше внести правку в предыдущий.

Comment: название вообще класс) лошадь + сено и выдало ошибку)